# Cascalog process multi-line json?

Tags: hadoop, clojure, cascalog

I have a directory of Json files that I want to process using cascalog.  The solution I have right now requires me to remove all newline characters from my json files using a bash script.  I am looking a better solution because I sync these files using rsync.

My question is can I read the contents of a file in Cascalog and return the contents of the file as one tuple.  At present the function 'lfs-textline' returns a sequence of tuples for each line in the file, hence why I have to remove the newline characters.  Preferably I want to return a sequence of tuples for each file.

```
(defn textline-parsed [dir]
    (let [source (lfs-textline dir)]
        (<- [?line]
            (source ?line))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hfs-wholefile from cascalog.more-taps to do this.

```
(:require [cascalog.more-taps :as taps])

(defn- byte-writable-to-str [bw]
  "convert byte writable to stirng"
  [(apply str (map char (. bw (getBytes))))])
```

And, use

```
(??<- [?str] 
    ((taps/hfs-wholefile path) ?filename ?file-content) 
    (byte-writable-to-str ?file-content :> ?str)
```